# Fastest way to find closest bounds from a series of values

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Let's say I have sorted precomputed floats:

```
1, 3, 10, 29
```

Let's say my "input" is `7.3`. I want my program to return 3 and 10 since they are the numbers in my array that are before and after 7.3.

What is the fastest method to do it? I'm assuming you can do it in `log(n)` time using binary search but is it possible to do it in constant time?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do in constant time. There is a slightly faster than log(n) approach but it requires the input to have an even distribution (which is not guaranteed in your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in constant time unless you limit the input to a small number of predetermined values.  Just use binary search.

The C++ function for binary search is `lower_bound`.  (There are others too but you want `lower_bound`.)

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you can do it in constant time but you can do it in log(log(n)) using [a van Emde Boas tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree) under certain assumptions. Binary search may be the best option in terms of implementation ease.